# Link between handwriting characters

Tags: css, fonts, digital-handwritting

I'm trying to use "Pacifico" (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico)
and this font as really strange behaviour.

When placed at the middle of a word, the W (or N) has not the same style than at the end of the word.
This is the example of the behaviour.

[image: w is not the same between how and why.]

I have the same issue with :

[image: same issue has you can see]

It looks like the renderer makes a link between the two characters.
I don't have this weird behaviour in Adobe Indesign, but seems like only in Chrome.

Is there a way to get a "w" in CSS at this end that looks like the w in why ?

[image]

Comment: Try `font-variant-ligatures: none;`

Comment: post it as an answer :) thank you it works

Comment: It's not strange behaviour it's the intended behaviour. Ligatures are used in order tighten the kerning of the letters that would otherwise look odd. Disabling the ligatures of this typeface would render the typeface in a different manner than the intended use. Please use caution in using this CSS property in doing so you will make the typeface look *strange*.

Comment: it was most an unexpected-for-me feature :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That aspect of font rendering can be controlled via [`font-variant-ligatures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-ligatures).

E.g. `font-variant-ligatures: none;`